# Sponsored tag images are not retina-sized

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags, retina

I realized that the images for sponsored tags are not retina-capable, despite the fact that the image is large enough to display in retina size, at least next to the small tag under a question.

[image: tag under question]

[image: tag page logo]

This may be nitpicking, but it would be nice to refine the logos.

Comment: I think it should be done by the sponsor. (to provide image of good qlty)

Comment: @SagarV Of course, but I have a suspicion that the __requested__ image sizes are not retina. Take a look at other sponsored tags as well.

Comment: Meh. Increase the download size of the page for all users, just so you can get a tiny, worthless little icon on a tag to be less fuzzy on your Retina display? I'll pass.

Comment: @CodyGray For all users? A well-coded website can simply detect the screen density and only load the larger image if it's necessary.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not a web programmer, so I really don't know about such things, but that isn't the implementation that I am familiar with. I mean, I guess you can conceivably do all things with Javascript, but now you introduce even more latency because you have to wait for the page & JS to load, do the detection, and then go *back* to the server for the appropriate image(s).

Comment: @CodyGray SO has already implemented retina images for other images on the site, so I don't think this will increase load time significantly.

Comment: The sprites are SVGs now, so they are infinitely scalable *and* faster to load. Every little bit counts when you're working on such a massive scale. I have a Retina display on my MBP, and the tag icons don't really look blurry to me.